# What is the most appropriate html tag for jquery click events?

Tags: jquery, html, css, standards

I'm fairly decent at jquery, but I'm working on something I want to be very standards based. The question I keep running into is.  What html tag to use to bind to a click event.  Buttons, spans, anchor tags, divs or something else.  First.  I can put an anchor tag with an href="#" but it shows up in the url when you click it. I don't know why that bothers me, but it does.

Do any have speed benefits over another, or is there a standard reason why you would choose a button over an anchor tag or a span for that case.

Appreciate the advice.  Is there a place that has a good list of standard practices that anyone can point me to? I've searched, and everyone seems to have a different approach.

Comment: Can you can be more specific about the click events being fired? There really is no "correct" element to which clicks should be bound - it depends on the context of what the click event does, for example there is no point putting all your click events on spans if you need one on a button, and there is no point putting click events on text elements if you are animating a div.

Comment: I'm working on a post/comment section similar to every other social network.  You can like a post, post a comment, like a comment.  I happened to notice that after a while there are hundreds of anchor tags in the thing.  I just really wanted to do it the most efficient proper way. I figured I'd ask.  Seems the consensus is there is no right way, just depends on the situation. I appreciate the help everyone!. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a specified tag on what an element should be to handle click events. For example, a menu displaying a submenu on click should be using <ul> and <li> tags, whereas a form validation button would be represented by a <button> element.

Usually I try to use the element the most relevant to the meaning of what I show to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that that is a bit openended unfortunately. Basically I would summarize the answer to be:

Bind your click event to whatever makes the most UX sense/provides the best ease of use for end users without having to do extra styling to for example make a div look like a button.

That being said most users will expect to click on a button or an anchor and have less automatic instinct to click on other elements. To make a anchor look nicer you can use a fake link that approximates what you are doing and then do a `event.PreventDefault()` call.

Answer (score 1):

**You should do whatever works best semantically**.

What makes sense in the given context? Sometimes a button is the best solution, sometimes it's an anchor link.

In Single Page Applications, you still use links, even though you're not actually sending any requests. But you want stick with them, as they make sense to the user, as they know links are used for navigating around your site - changing your browsers history.

Buttons should be used when you want something to happen that has nothing to do with navigation, like opening a modal, toggeling functionality, etc.

With that said, you can do whatever you want! HTML is nothing more than semantics. After all, the browsers interpret the meaning of your HTML, and there is nothing your can do about it. There is no technical reasons for not doing it one way or another.

Comment: Nice.  You're right, it's just my OCD kills me on this.  If i can style an anchor a span and button the same. Which is the best one.  I'll take my pills and use whatever makes sense.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the most sensible HTML element for the action you are trying to do, this is semantic html.

For example if it is an action use a button, if it is navigation use an anchor tag.

For your anchor tag, perhaps the way you are executing your click event is more the problem try this to prevent the # from appearing in the url.

```
$('.myanchor').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // do something.
});
```